# Sharepoint scrollbars disabled in Chrome

Tags: sharepoint, google-chrome

On the page
https://connect.wels.net/AOM/schools/Pages/default.aspx

the scroll bars don't work (disabled) in Chrome. They are fine in other browsers. I would love to solve this. Sometimes it works in Chrome. Sometimes zooming in and out fixes it. Other times, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the common problem with Chrome Browser in Sharepoint, as Sharepoint is supporting Limited Functionality to the Chrome Browser.

It also happens with the Javascript Loading order in Sharepoint page.

I cant find any solution for this till date

Refer this : https://answers.uchicago.edu/page.php?id=24860

Answer (score 4):

This is answered at this site:

http://withinsharepoint.com/archives/256

> The cause is in fact a timing issue around execution of a specific bit of very important onload JavaScript.
>
> The bit that doesn’t execute (and causes a systemic issue, one of the issues it causes is the scrolling weirdness), is:

```
body onload="if(typeof(_spBodyOnLoadWrapper) != 'undefined'; _spBodyOnLoadWrapper();"
```

> What this line means is basically if the page has loaded the onloadwrapper function from init.js. This onloadwrapper does a bunch of things, such as loading the ECMAScript for support SP.JS, executes page JavaScript for any onload events, and any client interactivity. So basically when this doesn’t execute pretty much no client side code from SharePoint can or will work, or any script that you have that relies on any of it. Scrolling is just the tip of the ice berg. Now for the good news, it’s easy to fix (I have a case in with Microsoft to look at including the fix in a future cumulative update).

Here's the fix that worked for me. Put this at the head of your master page. This will fix Chrome and Safari and also help your _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames functions work.

https://gist.github.com/alirobe/4224245
via http://withinsharepoint.com/archives/256

```
if (jQuery.browser.webkit) {
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var interval;
    function loopCheck() {
        if (typeof (_spBodyOnLoadWrapper) !== "undefined" && _spBodyOnLoadCalled == false) 
            _spBodyOnLoadWrapper();
         else 
            window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
    // Give SP a chance..
    setTimeout(function () { interval = window.setInterval(loopCheck, 30); }, 120);
});
}
```